# how to load tab bar items dynamically in ios?

Tags: ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have 2 tab bar items in popOver and there is plus button in popOver. When i click plus button i must remove currently displayed tab bar items and load other 3 tab bar items.

ex: tab1 and tab 2 are being displayed in popOver on launch.
user press '+'button from popOver toolbar, 
tab 3 , tab4 and tab5 has to be displayed in same popOver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating both your UITabBar items and when the popOver conditon is met swap your tabbars out.  Another idea would be to create another view with the second tabbar in it and just swap between UIViews.